# Emacs momentarily stalling with Flycheck

Tags: flycheck

I am using the GUI version of Emacs. I have noticed that while editing text, mainly in `js2-mode` with `Flycheck` enabled, the editor frequently stalls.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening or should I just not enable Flycheck mode constantly?